# brew link error libpng and libtiff

Tags: macos, homebrew, elixir

I tried installing elixir using homebrew and I got the following errors

```
==> Pouring libtiff-4.0.3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
```

File exists - /usr/local/lib
   Error: File exists - /usr/local/lib

I ran `brew doctor` and I saw this

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that  depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

libpng
libtiff
```

So I ran `brew link libpng` and I got this

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.17... Error: File exists - /usr/local/lib
```

I have no idea whats wrong. Any help

Comment: There are similar issues on Stack Overflow but with different packages. Have you tried them? Some recommend to run "brew link -f libpng" but you should investigate to be sure it won't mess up with your system.

Comment: @JoséValim I have tried several of those solutions including the one you mentioned above. No luck so far.

Comment: How 'bout doing `brew uninstall libpng` and then `brew install libpng`. Do the same for `libtiff` too. Have you tried that?

Comment: @WasswaSamuel if you don't have a lot of stuff in homebrew, consider nuking it and starting a new one. Alternatively, if you just want to play with Elixir, try kiex (https://github.com/taylor/kiex) or use the precompiled package (http://elixir-lang.org/install.html#precompiled-package). You can unpack it and run Elixir directly from bin. You can add bin to your PATH too if you want (that's actually how I run elixir :D).

Comment: This may not be an issue with the Elixir brew; you may want to try a different brew to see if you see the same issue.

Comment: @Gjaldon Tried those they don't work. Still bring the same error above

Comment: What does `file /usr/local/lib` say?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your `/usr/local/lib` folder, there are existing `libpng` symbols, hence `brew` doesn't want to overwrite them. It is a dependency of `elixir`, so it halts the setup.

If you are using MacPorts or Homebrew or installing anything manually, then dependencies might conflict. It's better to use one of them in a mutual exclusive way.

It's a viable choice to use Homebrew in overall since ease of use, if you are not going to build packages from source.

Homebrew does not work as how you would expect. As a default, it has a base directory to install the artifacts of `keg`s named `Cellar`, although it is configurable. Normally, you would copy the binaries to the `/usr/local/bin`, libraries to `/usr/local/lib`, headers to the `/usr/local/include` and so on... However, Homebrew installs them to its own directory and creates symbolic links on those directories instead, in order to make them function in same way.

You may find errors (or incompatibities) with `brew doctor` command. It'll tell you the symbols/files conflicting. You can delete them from file system manually, afterwards `brew` will create the symbolic links pointing to its base directory (upon your `brew link $PACKAGE_NAME` command).

## Experiment

When I suddenly decided to do a trivial `brew doctor` in my computer it did output some unexpected header files like so:

```
Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
```

However, it also states that those are no significance if everything works:

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!
```

First few lines from the output:

```
Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
  ...
```

This is not my personal computer, but it seems like someone installed `node` to this computer (actually user) manually. Trying to install it or anything dependent to it via `brew` would fail, in this case, since the upcoming header files would conflict with pre-installed ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with the following commands in succession:

`brew reinstall libtiff`
`brew reinstall gd`